# Access extention functions (values) through reflection in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection, extension-function

I would like to access Kotlin's extension functions/values through reflection.
I have a very simple example, but I cannot figure out what is wrong here

```
import kotlin.reflect.full.*

class A

fun A.ext() = 2
val A.value: Int
    get() = 2

fun main() {
    val a = A()
    val reflection = a::class

    reflection.members.joinToString(", ") { it.name }
    reflection.declaredMemberExtensionProperties.joinToString(", ") { it.name }
    reflection.memberExtensionProperties.joinToString(", ") { it.name }
    reflection.memberExtensionFunctions.joinToString(", ") { it.name }
    reflection.declaredMembers.joinToString(", ") { it.name }
}
```

This, of course, won't work in the [Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/8AQHv3yCV), because `kotlin-reflect.jar` is not in the classpath there.

Neither of the options produces the expected output: `ext` and `value`. What am I missing?

Comment: Extension functions are not members of the class unless they are declared within it. I would be surprised if reflection could simply list all extensions that involve that class. That would be like listing all functions that take instances of that class as a parameter. It would be an exhaustive search of all packages.

Comment: It's not quite true, see https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-do-extension-functions-work/609/3 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48635210/how-to-obtain-properties-or-function-declared-in-kotlin-extensions-by-java-refle, isn't it? In particular, "Extensions are visible from Java reflection as static methods in the classes they are defined in". If you look into definitions of `extensionProperties\Functions`, exactly static props/funcs must be listed.

Comment: "in the classes they are defined in" is the key part of that. If the extension function isn't defined inside the class, it isn't a member of that class. In Java reflection, you wouldn't look for `Arrays.fill()` in the `Object[]` class. It's a member of `Arrays`.

Comment: I followed the advice in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48635210/how-to-obtain-properties-or-function-declared-in-kotlin-extensions-by-java-refle). It's not ideal, but it works.