# Dynamic Icon value selector in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to dynamically set an icon value in Jetpack Compose?

Example, instead of:

```
Icon(Icons.Filled.Print, "print")
```

I'd like to do:

```
Icon(Icons.Filled.(iconValue), iconValueName)
```

Comment: what is this iconValue refered to as?

Comment: @RaBaKa78 It will have the same value as "Print" in string form but can be any icon like "Menu" or "Person". The problem is that icons are set dynamically from the web and I won't know what icon to set in Android until I get the value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Java reflection. I rely on the fact that each material icon is placed in a separate file, and all of them are declared under `androidx.compose.material.icons.filled` package.

```
@Composable
fun IconByName(name: String) {
    val icon: ImageVector? = remember(name) {
        try {
            val cl = Class.forName("androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.${name}Kt")
            val method = cl.declaredMethods.first()
            method.invoke(null, Icons.Filled) as ImageVector
        } catch (_: Throwable) {
            null
        }
    }
    if (icon != null) {
        Icon(icon, "$name icon")
    }
}
```

You can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48641786/3585796) for more details how Kotlin extensions are compiled to Java code.

I would also write a test for this logic using a couple of icons, just in case Compose changes something in future releases - a package name or moving multiple icons together in the same file, although this is unlikely.

Comment: Just because I could, I tried generating a source file with a `when` entry for every single icon. Generates just fine at about 10k lines, but compiling it crashes the compiler :'). I guess that answers the question why Compose doesn't offer this itself? Oh well, I'll use the reflection at runtime then.

Comment: How to do it in Kotlin Multiplatform using KClass?

Comment: @CaptainJacky kotlin reflection is much more limited comparing to java one, because it has to be supported on all the platforms. As I understand there's no analog for `Class.forName`, here's corresponding [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10440/Add-Kotlin-equivalent-to-Class.forName-for-KClass). In your place, I would have written a script to dynamically generate a Kotlin file with a huge `when` that could be added to the `commonMain` source files.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @phil-dukhov answer, here's a generalized implementation:

````
// File MaterialIconUtils.kt
package your.utils.package.goes.here

import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.BugReport
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.ImageVector

/** Regex to split icon name. */
private val splitter = Regex("\\.")
/** Prefix for Material icons package. */
private val iconsPackage = "androidx.compose.material."

/** Decodes a Material Icon using its "compose" name.
 *
 * For example:
 * - Icon `Icons.AutoMirrored.TwoTone.ArrowBack`
 * - Looks for class `androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowBackKt`
 * - Attempts to find method `getArrowBack(androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons$AutoMirrored$TwoTone)`
 * - Executes such method using static instance `Icons.AutoMirrored.TwoTone`
 *
 * Remember that Material Icons are organized as follows:
 * ```
 * Icons.Default.<iconName>  --> androidx.compose.material.icons.filled
 * Icons.Filled.<iconName>   -->  androidx.compose.material.icons.filled
 * Icons.Rounded.<iconName>  -->  androidx.compose.material.icons.rounded
 * Icons.Outlined.<iconName> -->  androidx.compose.material.icons.outlined
 * Icons.TwoTone.<iconName>  -->  androidx.compose.material.icons.twotone
 * Icons.Sharp.<iconName>    -->  androidx.compose.material.icons.sharp
 * Icons.AutoMirrored.Default.<iconName>  --> androidx.compose.material.icons.automirrored.filled
 * Icons.AutoMirrored.Filled.<iconName>   --> androidx.compose.material.icons.automirrored.filled
 * Icons.AutoMirrored.Rounded.<iconName>  --> androidx.compose.material.icons.automirrored.rounded
 * Icons.AutoMirrored.Outlined.<iconName> --> androidx.compose.material.icons.automirrored.outlined
 * Icons.AutoMirrored.Rounded.<iconName>  --> androidx.compose.material.icons.automirrored.rounded
 * Icons.AutoMirrored.TwoTone.<iconName>  --> androidx.compose.material.icons.automirrored.twotone
 * Icons.AutoMirrored.Sharp.<iconName>    --> androidx.compose.material.icons.automirrored.sharp
 * ```
 *
 * Also, don't forget to include in gradle:
 * ```
 * platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.02.01").also { compose ->
 *     implementation(compose)
 *     androidTestImplementation(compose)
 *     :
 *     implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core")
 *     implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended")
 *     :
 * }
 * ```
 *
 * @param name Icon name.
 * @param default Default icon if [name] is invalid.
 */
fun decodeMaterialIcon(
    name: String,
    default: ImageVector? = Icons.Default.BugReport
): ImageVector? =
    try {
        val parts = splitter.split(name)
        val className: String
        val typeName: String
        val iconName: String
        when (parts.size) {
            3 -> {
                className = buildString {
                    append(iconsPackage)
                    append(parts[0].lowercase())
                    append('.')
                    val type = parts[1].lowercase()
                    if (type == "default") {
                        append("filled")
                    } else {
                        append(type)
                    }
                    append('.')
                    append(parts[2])
                    append("Kt")
                }
                typeName = buildString {
                    append(parts[0])
                    append('.')
                    val type = parts[1]
                    if (type == "Default") {
                        append("Filled")
                    } else {
                        append(type)
                    }
                }
                iconName = parts[2]
            }
            4 -> {
                className = buildString {
                    append(iconsPackage)
                    append(parts[0].lowercase())
                    append('.')
                    append(parts[1].lowercase())
                    append('.')
                    val type = parts[2].lowercase()
                    if (type == "default") {
                        append("filled")
                    } else {
                        append(type)
                    }
                    append('.')
                    append(parts[3])
                    append("Kt")
                }
                typeName = buildString {
                    append(parts[0])
                    append('.')
                    append(parts[1])
                    append('.')
                    val type = parts[2]
                    if (type == "Default") {
                        append("Filled")
                    } else {
                        append(type)
                    }
                }
                iconName = parts[3]
            }
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid icon-name '$name'")
        }
        val typeClass: Any = when (typeName) {
            "Icons.Filled" -> Icons.Filled
            "Icons.Outlined" -> Icons.Outlined
            "Icons.Rounded" -> Icons.Rounded
            "Icons.TwoTone" -> Icons.TwoTone
            "Icons.Sharp" -> Icons.Sharp
            "Icons.AutoMirrored.Filled" -> Icons.AutoMirrored.Filled
            "Icons.AutoMirrored.Outlined" -> Icons.AutoMirrored.Outlined
            "Icons.AutoMirrored.Rounded" -> Icons.AutoMirrored.Rounded
            "Icons.AutoMirrored.TwoTone" -> Icons.AutoMirrored.TwoTone
            "Icons.AutoMirrored.Sharp" -> Icons.AutoMirrored.Sharp
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid icon-name '$name'")
        }
        Class.forName(className).getDeclaredMethod("get$iconName", typeClass.javaClass).invoke(
            null,
            typeClass
        ) as ImageVector
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        Log.d("icons", "Icon-error: ${e.message}")
        /* Note: if anything goes wrong:
         * - re-throw exception, or
         * - return a default icon (e.g. BugReport)
         *   Warning: this may introduce unexpected results, or
         * - return null - composables should not render icon, or use a different mechanism.
         */
        default
    }
````

To make it easier to use in composables, change signature to:

Note that to make it easier for composable and avoid nullables, just change signature as:

```
fun decodeMaterialIcon(
    name: String,
    default: ImageVector = Icons.Default.BugReport
): ImageVector = ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can then use a when statement and select appropriate image vector.

```
when(imageStringFromWeb) {
    is "email" -> {
        Icon(Icons.Filled.Email, null)
    }
    ...
}
```

*Edited to simplfy the code.*

Comment: Unfortunately, there are over a thousand icons used in Google Material Design. I am currently using net.steamcrafted:materialiconlib:1.1.5 but sometimes it has different names for the icons (Like "Print" is instead named as "Printer") and has not been updated in years.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Indeed there is no need. I thought the we get constant string references. When statement will not work this way obviously. I don't know how you can adapt to those changes.