# How to find the list of extension functions of a Kotlin class and its usages using reflection?

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I have this code so far but none of the methods return the myExtensionMethod function as expected:

```
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredFunctions
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMemberExtensionFunctions
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMemberExtensionProperties
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMemberFunctions
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMemberProperties
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMembers

fun main() {
    println(MyEntity::class.declaredFunctions)
    println(MyEntity::class.declaredMembers)
    println(MyEntity::class.declaredMemberProperties)
    println(MyEntity::class.declaredMemberFunctions)
    println(MyEntity::class.declaredMemberExtensionProperties)
    println(MyEntity::class.declaredMemberExtensionFunctions)
}

class MyEntity(
    var id: String,
)

fun MyEntity.myExtensionMethod() {
    println("Extension")
}
```

This is the output:

```
[]
[var MyEntity.id: kotlin.String]
[var MyEntity.id: kotlin.String]
[]
[]
[]
```

How do I retrieve myExtensionMethod via reflection? I am trying to find all callers of this method up until the controller layer, recursively and build a graph/tree data structure.

Docs - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html

Comment: Why does "retrieving `myExtensionMethod` via reflection" help with "finding all callers of this method"? These are separate problems, both of which are very difficult. This might be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: If the first problem can be solved in this question, I can workout the second problem. The second problem is my ultimate objective. I need the first problem to be solved before I can move on to the next one.

Comment: Okay, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48635210/5133585) help? It is very difficult if you don't know where the extension is declared.

Comment: The extension functions are spread all around the codebase